How does the 'use utf8' interfere with the 'Method::Signatures::Simple' module?
Have this code
use 5.034;
use warnings;
#use utf8;
binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)');

package User {
        use Method::Signatures::Simple;
        use Moose;
        has 'name' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', default => sub { return 'foo' });
        method xname { return "čč" . $self->name . "ňň"; }
}

my $u = User->new;
say $u->xname;

It nearly works as expected (not fully correct, because the source code containing utf8.)
After uncommentig the use utf8;  the perl -c throws errors:
Couldn't find declarator 'method' at /u/ae/envs/plenv/versions/5.38.2/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.2/amd64-freebsd/Devel/Declare/Context/Simple.pm line 47.
    Devel::Declare::Context::Simple::skip_declarator(Method::Signatures::Simple=HASH(0x8292a3fa8)) called at /u/ae/envs/plenv/versions/5.38.2/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.2/amd64-freebsd/Devel/Declare/MethodInstaller/Simple.pm line 62
    Devel::Declare::MethodInstaller::Simple::parser(Method::Signatures::Simple=HASH(0x8292a3fa8), "method", 1, 1) called at /u/ae/envs/plenv/versions/5.38.2/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.2/amd64-freebsd/Devel/Declare/MethodInstaller/Simple.pm line 25
    Devel::Declare::MethodInstaller::Simple::__ANON__("method", 1) called at /u/ae/envs/plenv/versions/5.38.2/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.38.2/amd64-freebsd/Devel/Declare.pm line 277
    Devel::Declare::linestr_callback("const", "method", 1) called at t line 10

Two questions:

why the simple use utf8 pragma interfere with the use Method::Signatures::Simple, and
how to use the Method::Signatures::Simple together with the use utf8?

EDIT:
@VonC suggested the Function::Parameters. It looks nice, but it not allows to use the method keyword in the Moose builder sub. E.g.
This not works for me,
    has 'foo' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', default => sub { return 'foo' });
    has 'foobar' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', builder => '_buildfoobar');
    method _buildfoobar {return $self->foo . 'bar' } #note the method

and must use the standard sub and $self shift
    has 'foo' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', default => sub { return 'foo' });
    has 'foobar' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', builder => '_buildfoobar');
    sub _buildfoobar {my $self=shift; return $self->foo . 'bar' }

Anyway, I will accept the solution, if no better comes, because it at least allows the utf8 :).
